# Как сделать ссылку в посте на категорию (рубрику) - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, link

Wordpress. На странице циклом выводится 20 постов разных категорий (рубрик). В каждом посте есть названия рубрики к которому прикреплен пост. **Вопрос: как сделать ссылку в посте на свою категорию?** Как правильно заполнить атрибут **"href"** к тегу **"a"**?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_category

Comment: Скиньте код, с помощью которого выводит названия рубрик

Comment: Да, спасибо Vantal  сразу не увидел в этой статье. Для тех кому искать лень, но читает комменты - ответ такой:

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( get_the_category() as $category ) {
printf(
    '<a href="%s" class="link link_text">%s</a>', // Шаблон вывода ссылки
    esc_url( get_category_link( $category ) ), // Ссылка на рубрику
    esc_html( $category->name ) // Название рубрики
);
```

}